# Force host setting group when ssh-ing via IP address

Tags: ssh, openssh

Suppose I have a `~/.ssh/config` file with a few settings to apply to `Host *.work.example.com` but sometimes I need to connect to hosts that doesn't yet have a DNS record.

I know of work arounds that are **not** practical:

- add host to `/etc/hosts`
- copy all the settings to the command line
- duplicate the settings to another file and use `ssh -F otherconfig`

and solutions that are not possible:

- move settings to the `Host *` section. I can't have the options applied to non-work hosts.

Is there a more practical way? Maybe something like `ssh -F` but that picks a host group from the default config file, instead of duplicating file contents? Or a way to provide ssh with a temporary hostname along with the IP address?

---

The openssh manpage shows `Host` as a possible option for `-o`, but when trying it I get this error:

```
Host directive not supported as a command-line option
```

Answer (score 2):

found a relatively practical workaround (that can easily be turned into an `alias`)

```
ssh -oHostname=<ipaddress> <fakehostname>

e.g.
$ ssh -oHostname=123.123.123.123 a.work.example.com
```